# I updated the temporary table and it updated the original table MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I ran this query to update the Temporary table `CTE_Companies` and it updated the original `Companies` table. What should I do now :(

```
with CTE_Companies
(ZIP)
As
(
Select ZIP from Companies
)

Update  CTE_Companies 
set CTE_Companies.ZIP= '0'+CTE_Companies.ZIP
where len(CTE_Companies.ZIP) = 4
```

Comment: get the last backup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common-table-expression is not a temporary table. It's more like a subquery on one or multiple tables. If you select from a single table then you'll update  this table.

That's by design and very useful since you can change the `Update`/`Delete` to do a `Select` easily to see what you are going to change or delete. So you should include the `Where` condition in the `CTE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update table expressions without base tables.
Use temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

WITH CTE_Companies
(ZIP)
As
(
Select ZIP from Companies
)

Update  CTE_Companies 
set CTE_Companies.ZIP= SUBSTRING (1, CTE_Companies.ZIP, LEN(CTE_Companies.ZIP) - 1)
where
    len(CTE_Companies.ZIP) = 5 
    and CTE_Companies.ZIP LIKE '0%'


-- check if your data is ok and then change the next line to COMMIT TRAN     
ROLLBACK TRAN
```